# force-directed graph using qgraph label colors don't match the nodes

Tags: r, graphics, distance-matrix

I'm using qgraph to plot a network graph from a distance matrix and I can't get the labels to match the colours of the nodes in the graph.

My code is as follows:

```
clr <- function(x) {
  known <- c(`Effluent`="seagreen", `Influent`="brown", `WWTP Animal`="skyblue",
             `Human`="red", `Aircraft`="lemonchiffon")
  known[x]
}

x <- read.table("Path/to/distance/matrix.tsv", sep="\t", header = T)
x <- 1 / as.matrix(x[,-1])


x_sub <- x[1:50,1:50]

grps <- data[,c("ID","Sample_type_grouped")]
grps <- grps[grps$ID %in% colnames(x_sub),]

grps <- grps[match(colnames(x_sub),grps[,"ID"]),"Sample_type_grouped"]

qgraph(x_sub, layout='spring', groups=grps, color=clr(grps))
```

[image: Here is an image of the final result]

Thanks for any help!

Comment: can you `dput` the `grps` object immediately before the `qgraph()` call, and also show the results of `clr(grps)`?

Comment: looking at the pdf for the package, try including `legend.mode = "groups"`?

Comment: Hey Paul,

  Thanks for the reply, dput(grps) returns this:

c("Effluent", "Influent", "Influent", "Effluent", "Effluent", 
"Effluent" ....)

While clr(grps) gives this:

Effluent       Influent       Influent       Effluent       Effluent       Effluent 
    "seagreen"        "brown"        "brown"     "seagreen"     "seagreen"     "seagreen" 
      Influent       Effluent       Influent       Influent       Influent       Effluent 
       "brown"     "seagreen"        "brown"        "brown"        "brown"     "seagreen" 
      Influent       Influent

Comment: I had tried with legend.mode="groups" and nothing changed.

Comment: can you share a reproducible example please?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to answer this without a reproducible example, but I think the problem is that you assign a color per node while also using the `groups` argument. If you use `groups` the `color` argument should only assign one color per group (so the length should be the number of groups). Here is an example dataset:

```
adj <- matrix(rnorm(10^2),10,10)
adj <- adj + t(adj)
groups <- c(rep("A",5),rep("B",5))
```

The following will not work:

```
library("qgraph")
qgraph(adj, groups = groups, color = ifelse(groups=="A","red","blue"))
```

As it doesn't show a blue node. This is because only the first two elements of `color` are used, which are both `red`. This does work:

```
qgraph(adj, groups = groups, color = c("red","blue"))
```